# Regex for Text Within Braces

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm a total noob to regexes. I'm trying to come up with a regex that will capture text in braces. Example:

```
{t} this text shouldn't {1}{2} be captured {3} -> t, 1, 2, 3
```

This is what I've tried:

```
NSString *text = @"{t} this text shouldn't {1}{2} be captured {3}";
NSString *pattern = @"\\{.*\\}";    // The part I need help with
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                       options:kNilOptions
                                                                         error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:text
                                  options:kNilOptions
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in matches)
{
    NSString *match = [text substringWithRange:result.range];
    NSLog(@"%@%@", match , (result == matches.lastObject) ? @"" : @", ");
}
```

It yielded `{t} this text shouldn't {1}{2} be captured {3}`.

I'm sorry for such a straightforward request, but I'm just in a hurry and I don't know much about regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Lookahead and Lookbehind

NSRegularExpressions support lookarounds, so we can use this simple regex:

```
(?<=\{)[^}]+(?=\})
```

See the matches in [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/15).

To iterate over all the matches, use this:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=\\{)[^}]+(?=\\})" options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:subject options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [subject length])];
NSUInteger matchCount = [matches count];
if (matchCount) {
    for (NSUInteger matchIdx = 0; matchIdx < matchCount; matchIdx++) {
        NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches objectAtIndex:matchIdx];
        NSRange matchRange = [match range];
        NSString *result = [subject substringWithRange:matchRange];
    }
}
else {  // Nah... No matches.
     }
```

**Explanation**

- The lookbehind `(?<=\{)` asserts that what precedes the current position is an opening brace
- `[^}]+` matches all chars that are not a closing brace
- The lookahead `(?=\})` asserts that what follows is a closing brace

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: FYI added regex demo and explanation for the pattern. :)

Comment: Worked perfectly. I'll accept in a couple minutes when it lets me :D

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again, but I have a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874163/replace-regex-matches-in-string-with-variable-image-in-objective-c